# Issue getting HTTPS working for subdomain despite "Certificate issued successfully"

Tags: kubernetes, ingress, cert-manager

Part of my struggle to learn this, I think, is that `cert-manager` is updated pretty regularly so a lot of the tutorials, blog posts, questions, and courses I have read or taken are no longer relevant.

For example, when I initially started learning Kubernetes you had to make `certificate.yaml` that looked similar to this:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: test-domain-com
spec:
  secretName: test-domain-com
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: test.domain.com
  dnsNames:
    - test.domain.com
  acme:
    config:
      - http01:
          ingressClass: nginx
        domains:
          - test.domain.com
```

This doesn't appear to be the case anymore since it seems to be extrapolated from the `issuer.yaml` and `ingress.yaml`.

Anyway, I have a certificate that "issued successfully", but still HTTPS is not working on the application when I navigate to it.

**issuer.yaml**

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: test-domain-com
spec:
  secretName: test-domain-com
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: test.domain.com
  dnsNames:
    - test.domain.com
  acme:
    config:
      - http01:
          ingressClass: nginx
        domains:
          - test.domain.com
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test.domain.com
      secretName: test-domain-com
  rules:
    - host: test.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: api-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 5000
```

**Certificate Logs**

```
$ kubectl describe certificates test-domain-com
Name:         test-domain-com
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"cert-manager.io/v1alpha2","kind":"Certificate","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"test-domain-com","namespace":"de...
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-01-30T17:49:12Z
  Generation:          6
  Owner References:
    API Version:           extensions/v1beta1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Ingress
    Name:                  ingress
    UID:                   d31883d9-4388-11ea-84ec-469fd0fd8fec
  Resource Version:        832245
  Self Link:               /apis/cert-manager.io/v1alpha2/namespaces/default/certificates/test-domain-com
  UID:                     d3222905-4388-11ea-84ec-469fd0fd8fec
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    test.domain.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:      cert-manager.io
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    Name:       letsencrypt-staging
  Secret Name:  test-domain-com
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2020-01-30T18:12:41Z
    Message:               Certificate is up to date and has not expired
    Reason:                Ready
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
  Not After:               2020-04-29T17:12:40Z
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From          Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----          -------
  Normal  Requested  43m   cert-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "test-domain-com-566504257"
  Normal  Issued     42m   cert-manager  Certificate issued successfully
```

**Describe Secret**

```
$ kubectl describe secret test-domain-com
Name:         test-domain-com
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  cert-manager.io/alt-names: test.domain.com
              cert-manager.io/certificate-name: test-domain-com
              cert-manager.io/common-name: test.domain.com
              cert-manager.io/ip-sans: 
              cert-manager.io/issuer-kind: ClusterIssuer
              cert-manager.io/issuer-name: letsencrypt-staging
              cert-manager.io/uri-sans: 

Type:  kubernetes.io/tls

Data
====
ca.crt:   0 bytes
tls.crt:  3566 bytes
tls.key:  1675 bytes
```

`ca.crt` is empty and not entirely sure if it should or shouldn't be. Looks like there is a [Github issue](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/2111) about it.

**Errors in `cert-manager` log**

```
W0130 19:13:11.357728       1 client_config.go:543] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
E0130 19:14:21.811114       1 controller.go:230] cert-manager/controller/webhook-bootstrap/webhook-bootstrap/ca-secret "msg"="error decoding CA private key" "error"="error decoding private key PEM block" "resource_kind"="Secret" "resource_name"="cert-manager-webhook-tls" "resource_namespace"="cert-manager" 
E0130 19:14:21.811257       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/webhook-bootstrap "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="error decoding private key PEM block" "key"="cert-manager/cert-manager-webhook-tls" 
rce_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="test-domain-com-566504257-1006673842-2382236481" "resource_namespace"="default" "type"="http-01" 
E0130 19:16:21.262484       1 sync.go:184] cert-manager/controller/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="wrong status code '404', expected '200'" "dnsName"="test.domain.com" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="test-domain-com-566504257-1006673842-2382236481" "resource_namespace"="default" "type"="http-01" 
E0130 19:16:42.616965       1 controller.go:156] ingress 'default/cm-acme-http-solver-6xj55' in work queue no longer exists
E0130 19:16:42.837328       1 sync.go:59] cert-manager/controller/orders "msg"="failed to update status" "error"=null "resource_kind"="Order" "resource_name"="test-domain-com-566504257-1006673842" "resource_namespace"="default" 
E0130 19:16:42.837364       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/orders "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on orders.acme.cert-manager.io \"test-domain-com-566504257-1006673842\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="default/test-domain-com-566504257-1006673842" 
E0130 19:16:43.687987       1 controller.go:193] cert-manager/controller/challenges "msg"="challenge in work queue no longer exists" "error"="challenge.acme.cert-manager.io \"test-domain-com-566504257-1006673842-2382236481\" not found"
```

The only thing that jumped out to me was:

`"msg"="error decoding CA private key" "error"="error decoding private key PEM block"`

Tried to dumping browser cache, incognito mode, etc... still comes up HTTP or "Not Secure" with "Fake LE Intermediate X1" certificate when navigating to HTTPS.

So what did I screwup/overlook this time and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out. It was due to using `staging` like so:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: <email>
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

Changed it `prod` like so and that cleared up the issue:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: <email>
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

Apparently that is the expected behavior when using `staging` according to [this well written and accurate tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes).

That being said I didn't initially think it worked. Even after a hard reload and empty cache + hard reload, HTTPS still wasn't working. Tried incognito and it worked, so closed all my browser instances, reopened, and HTTPS worked.

And also, `certificate.yaml` was not necessary at all.